# How would I make a basic select list?

Tags: 7, forms

So I am learning the ways of the <strike>jedi</strike> Drupal, but I have come across a part of a problem in what I am doing.  I am currently trying to make a basic select list with two options.
So far I have something like this.

```
function form_ee_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['select_list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select One for Data Rundown',
    '#value' => t('Okay'),
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken directly from [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select). Familiarize yourself with it.

```
$form['selected'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Selected'),
       '#options' => array(
         0 => t('No'),
         1 => t('Yes'),
       ),
       '#default_value' => $category['selected'],
       '#description' => t('Set this to <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
   );
```

EDIT

To print the result from the selection, you could consider a few things:

1. Do not use a form at all. Just use theme_item_list wherein you create hyperlinks to pages with nodes or users.
2. Use the form, but persist the user's selection (node or user) to the database or SEESION. Then when the form is created you reload the persisted value from the database or SESSION (if not present use default) as the default value so it always reflects the user's last choice, and you create a markup element wherein you show either the nodes or users that were the result of the selection or the default. In the submit you only persist the value to the database or SESSION. In the form creation you look at the persisted or SESSION value (if present, else use default), and display it in the markup element.
3. Use the form, do not persist anything in the database, and in the submit you inspect the select list value, and depending on the value you redirect (using $form_state) to a page that will show either nodes or users.
4. Create a jump list: for example [ARCHIVE: Example: How to Create a 'Jump Menu' from a List View](https://www.drupal.org/node/186211)

Comment: This seemed to work for me I took a look at the api, I am curious then, if I wanted to allow a user to select one of the select list options, how could I show the list of entities per say if the select list contains Nodes and Users.  That would be inside the SUBMIT function correct?

Comment: I don't quite get your comment, but this post [form_example_tutorial.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_tutorial.inc/7), together with the Form API, should answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: So I seem to not be able to get this right :(  What I am trying to do is list all nodes made from a selection on a drop down list. So with this `$form['selected'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Select one below!'),
       '#options' => array(
          0 => t('Node'),
          1 => t('Users'),`  If someone selects node, I want to print all nodes out to the user.  If someone selects users same thing as that.

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is options:

```
$form['select_list'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Select One for Data Rundown',
  '#value' => t('Okay'),
  '#options' => array(
    'option-1' => 'bar',
    'option-2' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```

The array key of options is used as the `<option>`'s value attribute, and the array value is used for the element's inner text.